# Create a new table with rows in order of ascending

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has a table that has rows with a value "ID" that changes a lot. 
It may be like:

---

row1.ID = 5, 
row2.ID = 47, 
row3.ID = -6, 
etc.

---

Completely random order.
Can I make another table when I load a page that will take all of the rows in the first table and create a second table arranging them in order of the "ID" value.
So the second table would be:

---

row1.ID = -6, 
row2.ID = 5, 
row3.ID = 47, 
etc.

---

Does that make sense?

Comment: You want two different databases or two different tables?

Comment: Sorry, two different tables. I'll go edit that in.

Comment: Answered, check this out - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by

Comment: In the relational model, rows *have no natural order* in a table. So your question is meaningless. Use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I didn't know that :) Mine were sorting by the enter date but now I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the easiest answer is to use `ORDER BY` when you query your table, and then you can control the order of rows in the query result set.  But I assume you mean you want the "natural" order of rows to be in numeric order when you don't use `ORDER BY`.

If your table uses the InnoDB storage engine, the default order when you query without using `ORDER BY` is always the order of the primary key.  That's because InnoDB stores tables as a *clustered index* by primary key.  So if ID is your primary key, and you convert your table to InnoDB, then you can rely on its natural order.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE MyTable ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If your table is stored as MyISAM, the natural order is the order rows are physical stored in the data file, which has nothing to do with the order of the values or even the order in which you created the rows.

For these tables, you can dump your table in primary key order with:

```
$ mysqldump --order-by-primary databasename tablename > table.sql
```

Then restore the table.  The data will reload in primary key order.  Then subsequently the default order when you query without using `ORDER BY` will be by ID.  But this doesn't prevent the rows from getting out of order again as the values change.

---

Re your comments:

The best option would be to use `WHERE`.  That's efficient because it can use the clustered index to find the correct row very quickly.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 6;
```

The alternative, which is less efficient but still better than returning all the rows, is to pick some row or rows by their position in the stream, instead of by their value.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5;
```

The first number is how many rows you want, the second number is how many rows to skip first.

Normally you'd want to use `LIMIT` only after specifying an order, otherwise you could get the rows in some meaningless order, and the fifth row wouldn't be any more desirable than the first row.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5;
```

Comment: Oh, I had no clue it ordered by the primary key! That's good to know (this is only my second day with mysql). I'm not sure if I use InnoDB but I think using Order By like you said will work best for me... so my question is, if I wanted to grab a specific raw after organizing with order by (no need to create a new table now) how would I do that? I'm assuming it's going to involve creating an array that has the rows of a table ordered by my variable "ID" ... But I don't know where to go from there /: Thanks for all the help so far! Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: For example would I do something like this to fetch the 5th row after ordering the array?
`$table1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());`
`$orderedArray = mysql_fetch_array($table1[5]);`
`$row5id = $orderedArray['id'];`

Comment: You can use the `LIMIT` clause to pick out a certain row or rows, and skip some.  Or else if you want to pick a certain row based on its primary key value, that's even more efficient.  You'd do this with the `WHERE` clause.  It might be useful to get a book or a tutorial on MySQL if you're going to be using it.

Comment: I looked it up and I'm not quite sure I understand fully how the Limit clause works or what it does, can you provide some insight? And yes, I will definitely be buying some books soon! (:

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ORDER BY ID` to your select cmd, don't create a second table just for ordering?

Comment: So if I wanted to grab the 10th row after I used ORDER BY ID how would I do that? This is only my second day with PHP and MySQL /: Bear with me :)

Comment: If you want to fetch a particular row, you should never rely on the database order, fetch it with `WHERE ID = 10` for example. You should update your question or ask another one with what you are really doing (why the 10th row for example).

Comment: Well the IDs will be random numeric values... I will put them into an array by ordering them in ascending order. Then, after I have my array, how would I get for example the 3rd row in that array (the row with the 3rd highest value for 'id' in my original table)... I thought I would do something along the lines of this, but I can't figure it out: `$table1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());` `$orderedArray = mysql_fetch_array($table1[3]);` `$row3id = $orderedArray['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it since even if you theoretically* save them in the right order you have to use `ORDER BY` operator to return it in right order, otherwise DBMS may return it in any order

> ORDER BY is the only way to sort the rows in the result set. Without
>   this clause, the relational database system may return the rows in any
>   order. (From [ORDER BY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by) - Wikipedia)

So anyway you have to use `ORDER BY` (if it wasn't clear from my answer - this is **edit**)

*theoretical way:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY ID
```

`table1` and `table2` should have the same schema